# Kotlin generic properties issue

Tags: android, generics, inheritance, kotlin, kotlin-generics

I got some issues with Kotlin when translating my android project from java to Kotlin.
Say i have interface I and interface O which extends interface I.

```
interface I{

}

interface O: I{

}
```

And generic class A which have generic parameter V that extends interfaceI, and generic class B which extends class A:

```
abstract class A<V: I> {

}

class B : A<O>() {

}
```

When i'm trying to create such property:

```
val returnB: A<I>
    get() = b
```

I'm getting compiler error 'required A, found B'. In Java this will work without any issues. How can i access this using Kotlin ?

I need to use this approach for Basic classes in my application.

BaseViewModel which have generic parameter for Navigator class:

```
abstract class BaseViewModel<N>(application: Application, val repositoryProvider:
RepositoryProvider) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    var navigator: N? = null

    fun onDestroyView() {
        navigator = null
    }

    open fun onViewAttached() {

    }
}
```

BaseActivity class:

```
abstract class BaseActivity<T : ViewDataBinding, V : BaseViewModel<BaseNavigator>> : AppCompatActivity(),
        BaseFragment.Callback, BaseNavigator {

    // .......

    private var mViewModel: V? = null

    /**
     * Override for set view model
     * @return view model instance
     */
    abstract val viewModel: V

    // .......
}
```

BaseNavigator interface uses for VM - View communication:

```
interface BaseNavigator {

    fun invokeIntent(intent: Intent?, b: Bundle?, c: Class<*>?,
                     forResult: Boolean, requestCode: Int)

    fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment, addToBackStack: Boolean)

    fun showDialogFragment(fragment: DialogFragment?, tag: String?)

    fun showToast(message: String?)
}
```

Here example code where i'm extending these classes:

AuthViewModel:

```
class AuthViewModel(context: Application, repositoryProvider: RepositoryProvider) : 
BaseViewModel<AuthNavigator>(context,repositoryProvider) {

       // ....

    }
```

AuthNavigator:

```
interface AuthNavigator : BaseNavigator {
    fun requestGoogleAuth(code: Int)

    fun requestFacebookAuth(callback: FacebookCallback<LoginResult>)
}
```

And AuthActivity class where error was appeared:

```
class AuthActivity : BaseActivity<ActivityAuthBinding, BaseViewModel<BaseNavagator>>(),
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, AuthNavigator {

@Inject
lateinit var mViewModel: AuthViewModel    

override val viewModel: BaseViewModel<BaseNavigator>
    get() = mViewModel     // Required:BaseViewModel<BaseNavigator> Found:  AuthViewModel
```

}

I'm also tried to change generic parameter in AuthActivity from BaseViewModel to AuthViewModel, but compiler throws error 'required BaseViewModel'.

```
And i tried to change

override val viewModel: BaseViewModel<BaseNavigator>
        get() = mViewModel

to 

override val viewModel: AuthViewModel
        get() = mViewModel
```

but in this case compiler throws error 'Property type is 'AuthViewModel', which is not a subtype type of overridden'.

**update:** 
That works when i add out property to BaseViewModel:

```
BaseViewModel<out N : BaseNavigator>
```

But in this case i can only create

```
private var navigator: N? = null
```

which i need to be public so i can set it in the Activity class. Can i create public setter for this property?  When i'm trying to create setter an error occurs:

```
private var navigator: N? = null

fun setNavigator(n: N) {   // error: Type parameter N is declared as 'out' but occurs in 'in' position in type N
    navigator = n
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are expecting the type parameter to behave *covariantly*. Kotlin uses declaration-site variance. If you do not specify the variance, generic type parameters are *invariant*.

In other words, right now there is no relationship between `A<I>` and `A<O>`. But if you declare

```
abstract class A<out V : I>
```

then `A<O>` is a subtype of `A<I>`.

(There is also `<in>` for contravariance, which works the other way around. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html for more details.)

Comment: Thanks, method works for now. But as i listed in update: i cannot create public var navigator so i can set it in activity class or fragment.

Comment: @VladMorzhanov With covariance, `mViewModel as BaseViewModel<BaseNavigator>` is allowed. If you had a setter, `(mViewModel as BaseViewModel<BaseNavigator>).navigator = object : BaseNavigator { ... }` would typecheck, but is clearly unsafe.